# python socket recv() and signals

Tags: python, sockets, signals, alarm

i have a simple (non-threaded) script that listens on a socket for data, analyses it and uses internally `SIGALRM`'s to send emails at predefined timer internals.

the problem is during the `recv()` loop, the occurrence of the `SIGALRM` appears to raise a

```
socket.error: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

and hence terminating the program.

i can wrap the `recv()` with a try/except block, but i was wondering whether i would loose any data during this time, or whether the buffer will prevent loss.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
while True:
    try:
        data = s.recv(2048)
    except socket.error, e:
        pass
    yield data
s.close()
return
```

Answer (score 9):

The standard way to handle this in C is to loop around `EINTR`. And, while that *shouldn't* be necessary in Python, it is.

Your code is pretty close to the idiomatic way to deal with this, except for two things:

- You don't want to ignore *all* errors, just `EINTR`.
- You can't `yield data` after ignoring an error that way, because you'll re-yield the previous packet (if there is one) or raise a `NameError` (if this is the first time through the loop).

So:

```
while True:
    try:
        data = s.recv(2048)
    except socket.error, e:
        if e.errno != errno.EINTR:
            raise
    else:
        yield data
```

---

So, why do you have to do this?

POSIX allows almost any syscall to return EINTR for certain kinds of temporary failure—which includes being interrupted by a signal. Many POSIX platforms do this. The expected application behavior is to just retry (if you were trying a blocking call) or go back around the loop (if you're inside a level-triggered reactor). [This blog post](http://www.250bpm.com/blog:12) gives a pretty good explanation for why POSIX works this way. (It's a justification after the fact, and definitely not the actual rationale…) Also see [the glibc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Interrupted-Primitives.html).

Like most scripting languages, Python is supposed to wrap all `EINTR`-prone calls internally, so you shouldn't ever have to think about this (unless you're using third-party C extensions). But unfortunately, it has bugs. The most recent set of cases that were found and fixed are in [issue 9867](http://bugs.python.org/issue9867) and [issue 12268](http://bugs.python.org/issue12268).

Even if they've finally caught everything, that only helps if you can depend on a sufficiently new version of Python. Given that you're using pre-2.6-style `except` syntax, and the latest fixes went in to some 2.7.x and 3.2.x bugfix release, that presumably doesn't work for you.

---

There are other ways to solve this problem, but they're more complicated and less portable. For example, you can replace your blocking `recv` with a blocking `pselect` and a non-blocking `recv`, add a `pipe` into the fd set along with the socket, replace all of your signal handlers with functions that just write (one byte) to that pipe, and move the actual signal-handling code into the event loop. Then, on some platforms, you will never get an `EINTR`. But this probably isn't the approach you want to take in Python.